# How can I include the content from an existing pdf into my generated pdf?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I'm using fpdf for the script to create the PDF from my sql data.  I want to add a glossary to the end of that content.  I looked at fpdi, but you can only add 1 page from the PDF.  How can I add all the pages?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1):

From the [FPDI documentation](http://www.setasign.de/support/manuals/fpdi/fpdi/fpdi-importpage/)...  Note the first parameter.

---

## FPDI::importPage()

**Description**

```
class FPDI extends FPDF_TPL {

    mixed importPage ( integer $pageno[, string $boxName='/CropBox'] )
}
```

Transforms a source page to a FPDF_TPL template and returns the id of created "template" (or page in this case).

**Parameters**

*`$pageno`*

- The page number to import.

*`$boxName`*

- The box which should be used to display the imported page.

  Possible values are:

  - /MediaBox
  - /BleedBox
  - /TrimBox
  - /CropBox
  - /ArtBox

  If a box is not found, FPDI will look up for it's parent box and use this instead. You can check which box were imported with FPDI::getLastUsedPageBox().

**Return Values**

If the page was imported correctly the method will return the id of the template (page) to use with useTemplate(). If you define a wrong box in the 2nd parameter the method will return *false*

Answer (score 0):

How about using a loop to import each page separate.

Should not be to difficult to get the number of pages then loop through the pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile('yourpdf.pdf'); 

// import pages
for ($loop = 1; $loop <= $pagecount; $loop++) {
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($loop);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);
}
```